# Should I use the manufacture's print driver instead of secure AirPrint?

Tags: printing

I've noticed that macOS appears to default to using secure AirPrint as it's printer driver over the manufacture's printer driver. Any reason why I should choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this.

In the near future, there will be a macOS update. Your printer manufacturer may or may not release a timely driver update that matches the updated OS. As a result, your system may become unstable, not be able to print or worse.

My strong suggestion is that, unless there's some mission-critical functionality you need, it's always best to go with the built-in drivers. With it, there's a much higher probability that your system will remain stable through multiple OS updates.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me with Catalina. Xerox promised drivers and 5 months later it's still coming "soon."